# Excel 2007 vba macro: error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code, written for me by @Jon49 that i adapted to suit my purposes :
The problem i have with this code is that it works for some of my files but produce an error 9 subscript out of range on others. essentially i have a loop that opens every file in a folder in turn performs the foloowing code. saves it then closes it before opening another one. The format of all the files is the same. so what is producing the error??

When the error happens and i debug it it tends to show the cause some where here :

```
sData(j, 7) = vData(1, j + 10)
sData(j, 8) = vData(i, j + 10)
sData(j, 9) = vData(3, j + 10)
sData(j, 10) = vData(2, j + 10)
```

**SCROLL to BOTTOM  for what i think is causing the error**

Here is the code:

```
Range("k1").Select
Dim Parameters As String
Parameters = Range(ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell).Count
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim rData As Range
Dim sData() As String, sName As String
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim vData As Variant
Application.EnableEvents = False     'Initialize worksheets
Set wks = ActiveSheet      'Get data
Set rData = wks.UsedRange
vData = rData
ReDim sData(1 To Parameters, 1 To rData.Columns.Count - 10)
rData.Offset(1).Clear
rData.Offset(11).Resize(1).Clear
```

<---- ??? not sure about importance of the line above because i commented out and the code will still work

```
For i = 1 To UBound(vData)
  For j = 1 To UBound(sData)
    For k = 1 To 6
      sData(j, k) = vData(i, k)
    Next k
    sData(j, 7) = vData(1, j + 10)
    sData(j, 8) = vData(i, j + 10)
    sData(j, 9) = vData(3, j + 10)
    sData(j, 10) = vData(2, j + 10)
  Next j         'Print transposed data
  wks.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
  .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(sData), UBound(sData, 2)) = sData
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

---

```
Range("K1").Select
Range(ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell).Delete
Rows("2:" & Parameters + 1).Delete
```

[image] 
[image]
[image]

**One thing that i noticed is the files that the error seems to be produced on 
has few parameters ( the two files ive noticed it erroring so far have 9 [will debug to sData(j, 10) = vData(2, j + 10)] and 7 [sData(j, 8) = vData(i, j + 10)]parameters each ) the others it is okay with so far each have more than 10 parameters .   parameters being CH4, NO, NO2 etc**

Comment: rData.Offset(1).Clear
rData.Offset(11).Resize(1).Clear  --> These lines just clear out the old data so you have a clean sheet. I thought about creating a new sheet, deleting the old one, and then renaming the new one to the old one, but thought it would be faster just to clear everything out except for the headers. Let me know if you have any other questions about what different parts of the code does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access a value which doesn't exist in your sData or vData array. One or both of them have fewer "rows" or "columns" than you think.  Try adding:

```
Msgbox "sData: #rows=" & ubound(sData,1) & "   #cols=" & _
        ubound(sData,2) & vbcrlf & 
       "vData #rows=" & ubound(vData,1) &  "   #cols=" & ubound(vData,2)
```

Immediately after

```
ReDim sData(1 To Parameters, 1 To rData.Columns.Count - 10)
```

See what values you get.

Comment: Hey Tim. i put that code right after the ***********sData(j, 7) = vData(1, j + 10) sData(j, 8) = vData(i, j + 10) sData(j, 9) = vData(3, j + 10) sData(j, 10) = vData(2, j + 10)***** part and when it reaches an error and i debug nothign happens.  can u tell me where i should be putting this code?

Comment: Put it right after: ReDim sData(1 To Parameters, 1 To rData.Columns.Count - 10)   You should see the output in the immediate pane in the VB editor (Ctrl+G to show if not already open).  Or use a messagebox instead (edited my answer)

Comment: i got s data rows 7 columns 7 v data ros 8763 col 17 im not sure what that means towards why my code doesnt work but on another note. i fixed my problem! when u pointed out the redim line. i changed the -10 to -parameters and it works now.  if u could still explain how those numbers and columns tells it doesnt work this would be super helpful in the future!. thanks Tim

Comment: If sData is a 2-dimensional array with (in this case) 7 rows and 7 columns, then there is no element at (eg) sData(j,8)  That's why you get the "subscript out of range" error: 8 is "out of range", since there are only 7 "columns" in the array.